# Using integer in recursive call, return the wrong answer

Tags: java

when I pass (int curr = 0) into the dfs method, it returns 0, but if I used count[], it returns the correct answer, I don't quite understand the reason that the result is wrong when I change the curr [] into curr .

```
 public int maxAreaOfIsland(int[][] grid) {
        int row = grid.length;
        int col = grid[0].length;
        int max = 0;
        int[] curr = new int[1];
        for(int i=0;i<row;i++) {
            for(int j=0;j<col;j++) {
                if(grid[i][j] == 1) {
                curr[0] = 0;
                    dfs(grid, i, j, curr);
                    max = Math.max(max, curr[0]);
                }
            }
        }
        return max;
    }

    int[][] directions = new int[][]{{0,1},{0,-1},{1,0},{-1,0}};
    public void dfs(int[][] grid, int i, int j, int[] curr) {
        if(i<0||i>=grid.length||j<0||j>=grid[0].length||grid[i][j] == 0 )
            return;
        curr[0]+=1;
        grid[i][j] = 0;
        dfs(grid, i+1,j, curr);
         dfs(grid, i-1,j,curr);
        dfs(grid, i,j+1,curr);
        dfs(grid, i,j-1,curr);
        
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by *when I pass (int curr = 0)* ? The `curr` parameter is an *array of 
 `int`*.  Do you mean when you pass `new int[]{0}` or  `new int[]{}` or something else? Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates "working" and "not working" versions, and accurately describe  what "not working" means.

Comment: I dont understand why I should use an array(curr[]) to record the result, why can't I using just an int(curr) to record?

Comment: What do you mean by 'int(curr)'?

Answer (score 1):

Java passes arguments by value.  In

```
void A(int x) {
   x = 42;
} 

void B() {
   int y = 0;
   A(y);
}
```

the call of A is effectively 'use the value of `y` to initialize a local variable `x`'.  Subsequent operations on `x` have no connection to `y`.

In the array case, a reference to the array is passed by value (i.e., copied), but it's the same array.